# Ubuntu 23.10 consume lots of energy in sleep mode comparing to windows 11

Tags: suspend, power-management, 23.10

If i use windows 11 and suspend my computer, it almost dont consume energy.Even many hours after. Unlikely ubuntu 23.10 that consume energy. I did the experiment twice.

I have AMD Ryzen™ 5 5500U with Radeon™ Graphics × 12
And it is a lenovo laptop

Can ubuntu be improve to be as good as windows 11?
And waking from sleep doesnt work very well since, i have to force shutdown sometimes, to be able to get into the system, or suspention doesnt work very well

Will be there an update to fix this?

Comment: Can Ubuntu be improved to be as good as XYZ? Sure, if somebody is willing to pay for all the engineering work to investigate. Might be Ubuntu. Might be the Linux kernel. Might be kernel modules provided by manufacturers. Might be undocumented features secretly offered to Microsoft. Might be all of the above. Complain to your OEM -- they have your money.

Comment: could it be that fastboot on Win11 is still running in the background, therefore 2 OSs are running when you have Ubuntu suspended? https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup-on-windows-11 Windows is not supported on Ask Ubuntu though.